# MiKTeX in inconsistent state: warnings about "SlantFont/ExtendFont" only being usable with "embedded Type1 fonts"

Tags: fonts, miktex

I use MiKTeX/`pdflatex` (`This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2013.4.12)`). Even when I compile a plain, nearly empty document

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
Hello.
\end{document}
```

I get 16 warnings of the following form:

```
pdfTeX warning: pdflatex.exe (file C:/Users/<username>/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/pdfte
x/config/pdftex.map): invalid entry for `PTMono-<Slanted or BoldSlanted>-tlf-<somestring>--base': SlantFo
nt/ExtendFont can be used only with embedded Type1 fonts
```

where `<somestring>` has short values such as `x2`, `il2`, or `t2c`.

Whenever I update MiKTeX, I synchronize the package database (before and after, though I probably need to do it only once) and I click "Refresh FNDB" and "Refresh Formats" within the MiKTeX Options menu.

**What is happening? How can I get rid of the 16 warnings?**

*For a more general question about keeping one's MiKTeX installation free of inconsistencies, see this question: [How should one maintain and update a MiKTeX installation?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/108447/14996)*

Comment: **To the relevant folks in charge of MiKTeX (and `paratype`): Once this has been fixed, please let this community know, and someone can replace this comment by another one (or an edit of the question or of the answer) saying that `paratype` is ready to be added back in again without giving these warnings.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is an problem with the packaging (by MiKTeX) of package `paratype`. Delete it, update formats and refresh FNDB and your system should run again.  There is an error with the map file as far as I remember.

Before I do the update I always have a look on MiKTeXs homepage to see, if there are problems known with/after a update. There is no way to be always safe. Errors happen ...

Comment: Now the homepage has a link to this Q&A group, but was there information before then? Just checking.

Comment: @LoverofStructure Someone is always the first to notice the issue …

Comment: Thanks -- this really helped. A follow-up question: should one leave `paratype` uninstalled, or is it important to reinstall it?

Comment: @JoshO'Brien I'm sure this error will be fixed soon; it is/was a problem of packaging, not a problem of package `paratype`.