# How should one maintain and update a MiKTeX installation?

Tags: packages, installing, miktex, best-practices

Every once in a while after updating MiKTeX, the installation gets into an inconsistent state. This might be a problem with the packages (an example is described in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/108443/14996)), but sometimes packages are split or renamed. The cases I remember are when [`amslatex` was split into `amsmath` and `amscls`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/96778/14996) and when `miktex-etex-base-2,9` was renamed to `miktex-etex-base-2.9` (*if I recall correctly*; I am sure it was either that or something very similar). In each case the MiKTeX Update process suggested to remove the "old" packages but it didn't give the user any hints about him having to manually add the respective replacement packages back in the package manager to get one's MiKTeX installation back into a usable state.

**What are best practices for keeping MiKTeX up to date?** Note that I'm not asking about installing new packages or fonts in general; there are other questions covering this area.

- In which order should one execute the Update process and the Synchronization of the repository?
- [According to this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/108444/14996), it is recommended to check the MiKTeX homepage before updating. What else should one do?
- When and in which order (and why) should one execute the "Refresh FNDB" and "Update Formats" processes within the MiKTeX Options menu?
- What else can happen? Other advice?

Comment: It was `miktex-etex-base` before (without the versioning), IIRC.

Comment: It's worth mentioning Madam Ulrike Fischer's [comment to amsmath Q](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96778/a-miktex-update-removed-amsmath-as-obsolete-can-i-use-another-package-or-get-i#comment208006_96795) and she can give her practical best-practices answer here

Comment: I have TeX Live installed besides MiKTeX, in case something in MiKTeX gets messed up (see [Using MiKTeX and TeX Live on the same computer?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31211) and [Change from MiKTeX to TeX Live](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/89764)). Does that count as a “best practice”? `:)`

Comment: @doncherry Well ! that would too much best practices :).

Comment: @Speravir Okay. I do remember something happening with something with `2,9` in its name as well. (Perhaps it had both names at some point in time.)

Comment: @LoverofStructure I could remember wrongly, of course, and we can both be right: In a first step the erroneus renaming, in a second the typo correction.

Comment: See [What is the preferable setup for MiKTeX to keep all packages up-to-date easily?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29616)  for details of how to install MiKTeX for maximum ease of maintenance.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

### Addition 2018: The MiKTeX console

In 2018 a new tool, the MiKTeX console, appeared which unifies all the three previously used tools (settings, package manager, update manager).

You can check for updates, install new packages, add local roots and run most of the maintainance tasks with the console. Tabs to manage formats and languages have been added now too.

The console can operate in two modes (admin and user) and according to the documentation will ask on multiuser installation which mode you want to use. As described below you will need *both* modes.

Synchronization of the repositories can now be done through the tasks menu with the entry `tasks->Update package database`.

The FNDB can be updated with `tasks-> Refresh file name database`.

New in the tasks menu is the entry to recreate the font maps. This means that is no longer necessary to run `updmap` on a command line. `tasks->Refresh font map files` can be used instead.

Some documentation is here https://miktex.org/howto/miktex-console

### Edit 2018: Windows and Linux

When I wrote this answer MiKTeX did run only on windows. Now a Linuxversion appeared. Be aware that things can be different there, e.g. the installation needs some special steps (https://miktex.org/howto/install-miktex-unx). Check the documentation!

### Admin + User mode

If you have an multiuser installation you will have to maintain miktex in **both** modes. The admin mode alone can't do everything, it can't update packages installed by the user, it can't update formats and FDNB and map-files owned by the user.

So run the update manager in both modes and synchronize both package managers. Sometimes you will also have to create formats as user and update map-files (see below).

### Synchronization

[image]

Miktex has an offline database which contains informations about available packages, their content and how to install them. Miktex needs such an offline database for the on-the-fly installation: Beside other problems it would slow down the compilation a lot if miktex would download the informations every time a file is missing.

When new packages are added to the online repositories, or if for some reason packages are rearranged or renamed the offline database on your PC is no longer up-to-date and you should "synchronize" (menu repositories in the package manager). If you have multiuser installation synchronize in both package managers (admin + user). As you can't know if this is the case you should use sensible rule of thumbs: Synchronize every month, if the update manager has removed some package, before running a lot of updates, if you are looking for a new package, if you get curious errors.

### Updates

You should run regularly the update manager in admin + user mode to check for new packages. Before clicking on the "update" button, use your brain: updates do change the system and so can break it. Don't update when you don't have the time to handle problems. Don't update if packages are removed and you don't understand the implications. It doesn't do any harm to wait some days (I have miktex on three systems and their age differ by weeks).

### FNDB + formats + Map-files:

In general it is not necessary to do something about it if you install packages with the package manager.

But there are exceptions:

#### FNDB

If you install files **manually** you should always update the FNDB (in admin + user mode if you don't know which one is the right one), it doesn't do harm to do it when miktex doesn't seem to find something installed.

#### Formats

User formats (created with the button in the user version of miktex settings) wins over admin formats. The update manager (admin) can't update such a user format so you will (sometimes) have to do it yourself if you have such formats by clicking on the *update formats* button in miktex settings (user version).

In the format tab of miktex settings you can exclude and include the formats you want to create. *Formats that are excluded will never be updated automatically*. So if a format doesn't change check its status.

Sometimes miktex forgets to trigger the format generation after a update of base files. Then you should update the formats manually in miktex settings (admin or user depending on the location of the old formats).

The creation of a format can fail (this doesn't happen often). In this case build **one** failing format from the format tab in miktex settings, copy the error message and ask for help.

#### Map-files

In quite a number of multiuser installation the on-the-fly installation created user map-files. These must be updated manually by running `updmap` on a command line after installation of packages with type1-fonts.

### Critical Updates

Critical updates are updates which change core miktex packages (those starting with `miktex-` in the list).

It is difficult to impossible to revert the installation of the core packages. If after such an update a binary is broken it can impend your work heavily. So consider carefully if it is the right time to do the update. If you are in a production environment it is a good idea to wait a bit and check the mailing list and the bug tracker for reports.

In some cases such updates also need some new packages, e.g. newer versions of some `.dll` or some new tool. The update manager will not show you the new packages. It will also not warn you that these packages are needed and should be installed.

When you see an update list that looks as if it could be critical, it is a good idea to *first* start the package manager ((admin) in multiuser setups), synchronize the data base (menu `repositories`), check if there are uninstalled `miktex-`packages and to install them.

If you forgot this and miktex fails after such an critical update: **Don't panic**. You normally can install the missing packages with the command line version of the tools, or even manually after a download from CTAN.

Comment: I'll add one implication that follows from your writing: if one executes Synchronize *and* Update, one should do Synchronize first; that is, it wouldn't make sense to do it the other way round or to execute Synchronize a second time after Update.

Comment: @LoverofStructure: No. The update manager compares the list of installed packages with an online list. This is not affected by the synchronization. The synchronization status affects only the behaviour of the package manager and the on-the-fly-installations - when new packages (really new or due to renames) are involved.

Comment: I see. So: Are Update and Synchronize are more or less independent actions that can be run on different schedules? Or should one, because Update doesn't require Synchronize but Synchronize is affected by Update, run Synchronize every time after one runs Update?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: In my MikTeX 2.9 package manager under the "Edit" tab, the "Select Updateable Packages" is grayed out. Also the "update wizard" under the task tab gives a message box with a problem report saying that "Update helper could not be found". Could you please suggest how to locate and update my packages. Recently I had a frustrating experience with TikZ package. So basically I just uninstalled and reinstalled `pgf`. Since I do not have admin privileges I thought I should update them all at one go since at this very moment I have admin access to the package manager. Many thanks.

Comment: @AbhimanyuArora: Don't use the package manager to update. Start directly the update manager.

Comment: Just as a side note. Shouldn't the critical updates which "cause trouble" be marked as "experimental" or something in the update manager? I just completely screwed up my installation with no means of going back. Nice going there ...

Comment: @theswine: Sorry but if you see an update which obviously changes a lot of binaries and don't realize that this could be critical, then some marker wouldn't probably stop you either. Nothing can replace the use of your brain.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Actually I'm quite convinced it would. Not everyone checks all the packages that are being updated and definitely not everyone updates regularly. Probably most people only update when they want to use some new functionality from a recent version of a certain package. A warning dialog should not at all be too much to ask in order to save these people from accidentally destroying their LaTeX distribution. All it has to be is "Careful: this update will change core MiKTeX packages. Before updating, you should synchronize your repositories and install any missing `miktex-` packages."

Comment: Apparently the Package Manager has disappeared in the last few days (https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/86). Seems one ought to use the MikTeX console now: https://miktex.org/howto/miktex-console.

Comment: @moewe Yes, I already thought about this and now added an edit.